# How to make WPF Window appear in the "New" wizard in Visual Studio?

Tags: wpf, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I have an application that is currently based on WinForms and I am in progress of converting it to WPF. I added `PresentationFramework`, `PresentationCore` and `System.Xaml` as references. I now want to add a WPF dialog to this application, but when I right-click `File` / `New` and select `WPF` it only shows me the `UserControl`. What else do I have to add to make the other WPF stuff appear?

Edit: When I start a new WPF application or library, the items ARE there.

Comment: I would start a new WPF application and copy what you can use from the winforms project. Its the only way to have a clean 100% WPF application. Apart from that, why does it have to be WPF ? I choose winforms over wpf any day

Comment: I want to migrate to WPF because some GUI things are much easier than with WinForms (e.g. Databinding). It won't be a 100% clean WPF application because it needs a tray icon which is quite painful with WPF. But I will go the "cleaner" way - I already have a GUI project which houses all the user controls, and I will create another which houses the windows (as migration to VS2015 is the next thing, and its GUI designer has problems referencing user controls from the same project)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The templates Visual Studio suggests for adding new files depend on the project type. This is determined by the "ProjectTypeGuids" setting of your project.

Open your sample WPF .csproj file in a text editor. You will find a line similar to this:

```
<ProjectTypeGuids>{60dc8134-eba5-43b8-bcc9-bb4bc16c2548};{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}</ProjectTypeGuids>
```

You need to add this line to your migration project (or replace the existing one) to convert it to a WPF project.

(Sample config is from VS2015, so you should really double check with actual VS2010 projects)

Comment: I accept this as a solution, but I will do it by using a separate project / dll that holds the windows. I already have one with the User Controls. Migration to VS2015 is the next thing.